# Highlight columns with the same month value in RDLC report

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, rdlc

After exhausting many variations of IIf and count, I cannot get my desired outcome.

I have an RDLC report in a report viewer in a webforms application.

The report is assigned a dataset.

I need to highlight the column header where the MONTH name occurs twice. ( ie: where 2 columns / 2 textboxes have the same month name.

Additional methods I tried were to loop through the reports controls and check for controls of type TextBox but no luck - the report seems to use an update panel and a NoScriptControl control and even looping their controls I could still not see the textbox objects.

Please see attached example where 2 headers are coloured yellow with the same month. ( Ideally the whole column should be highlighted, but if I got the header highlighted then I'm sure I can figure out the other textboxes )

I would just use a gridview or a HTML table but the report was already in place and the export functionality is desirable by the user so they can export to PDF and excel.

I cannot use any other 3rd party controls like telerik, devexpress or syncfusion.

Many thanks in advance[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you can post the DataSet where you have the data, so we can have an Idea of what are you doing internally

Comment: The dataset is very very simple.... it contains data from 1 single table only, there are no relationships.  So basically I will have :

1) CustomerID
2) MonthNo
3) Year
4) Value1
5) Value2
6) Value3
7) Value4
8) Value5
etc...